# Springboot and mysql DB how to handle duplicate key entry

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot API that I want to use to connect my database to my iOS app, however i am not sure how to handle duplicate key exceptions. In my entity i have 4 unique fields i.e email, phone, username and id. My aim is to get an error message such as the following when a user attempts to enter a duplicate key:

```
"message"= "Error saving data, dublicate keys were found on username and phone number"
```

or something like:

```
"message"= "Error saving data, dublicate keys were found on username "
```

Currently I'm getting this error in the console but I want to show it to the user as an error response message:

[image]

This is my code currently:

```
 public ResponseMerchantQuery createMerchant(Merchant merchant) {
         String returnMessage = "";
         String merchantNumberMsg = "";

       if( merchant == null || merchant.getMerchantID()== null){
          throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Empty", "Missing Data Exception");
      } else {
           try{

          merchant.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(merchant.getPassword()));
          merchant.getDirectors().stream().forEach(director -> director.setMerchant(merchant));
          merchantRepository.save(merchant);
          String merchantNum = Long.toString(merchant.getMerchantNumber());
          returnMessage = "Merchant Created Successfully";
          merchantNumberMsg = merchantNum;

           }catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {

            returnMessage = ex.getCause().getMessage();
             merchantNumberMsg = "Unable to issue a Merchant Number";
           }

       return new ResponseMerchantQuery(merchantNumberMsg, returnMessage);
}

}
```

Merchant entity:

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "Merchant", 
    uniqueConstraints = 
              {
                    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "userName"),
                    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "phoneNumber"),
                    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "merchantID"),
                    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email")
            }
    )
    public class Merchant implements Serializable{
         @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int merchantNumber;

    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL}) 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "merchant")
     private List<Director> directors;

    @NotBlank
    private String userName;

    @NotBlank
    private String phoneNumber;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 5, max = 20, message = "Please enter between {min} and {max} characters.")
    private String password;

    @org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email(message = "Invalid Email")
    @Size(max = 254, message = "Your email address is too long")
    @Column @NotNull(message = "Please, enter the user email")
    private String email;
  ...

 }
```

Merchant Repository:

```
public interface MerchantRepository extends CrudRepository<Merchant, String> {

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of Merchant and the MerchantRepository

Comment: why cant you check if any merchant exists with those values and throw exception

Comment: i have added the repository and the merchant entity code. @pvpkiran how do i achieve that, ca u give me an example